# When using a babel.config.js as well as specifying options in webpack babel loader, would it merge both or ignore babel.config.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, monorepo

Hypothetically, if someone puts configuration of babel in three files at the same time:

1. `babel.config.js`
2. babel key in `package.json`
3. babel loader options/query in `webpack.config.js`

Then which one of them will be actually used as configurations during babel compilation?
How does Babel resolve which configuration to use in case of conflicting options given to it? I couldn't find exact priority order in the documentations.

Context of my question : I have a monorepo in which each package extends from root directory babel configuration and a webpack configuration also of the package itself which has its own babel configuration. In this case babel will use which configurations during compilation?